# Google Drive SDK getModifiedDate() different from setModifiedDate()

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I'm running into an issue with the 'setModifiedDate()' method of the '[Google Drive Web APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/)', and I don't know if it is by design, or a bug.

When updating modified date using the following construct:

```
  DateTime md = DateTime.parseRfc3339("2014-11-02T12:09:58.000-07:00");
  File body = new File().setModifiedDate(md);
  service.files().patch(id, body).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute();
```

the date/time updates correctly. Notice that input DateTime variable md can be shown as

```
2014-11-02T12:09:58.000-07:00, and 
md.getTimeZoneShift() reports -420 minutes
```

When later reading the file's modified date using for instance this construct:

```
FileList gLst = service.files().list().execute();
for (File gFl : gLst.getItems()) 
  md = gFl.getModifiedDate();
```

the DateTime 'md' variable holds the correct GMT time, but the time shift (UTC offset) info is lost.
the time would be reported as

```
2014-11-02T19:09:58.000Z and 
md.getTimeZoneShift() reports 0 minutes
```

which certainly IS CORRECT ZULU (GMT) time for the file, but the fact that it was modified from my timezone (GMT-07:00) is lost. I would expect to get the same DateTime format, i.e.

```
2014-11-02T12:09:58.000-07:00 
and md.getTimeZoneShift() reports -420 minutes
```

as I patched.

Is it the correct behavior, or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not a bug as it is converted correctly, taking the original offset into account, and there does not appear to be an additional flag for special handling regarding it.

It makes sense to store the values in plain UTC server-side as calculations and all kinds of actions can become much simpler and faster. The [File.getModifiedDate()](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getModifiedDate()) method documentation is fairly basic as well, stating that the DateTime is going to be a formatted [RFC 3339](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) timestamp. Taking that into account, even if you were being delivered the "correct" time zone, you should not depend on it and you should write code that deals with the time zone dynamically just in case all of a sudden you get delivered a DateTime with an offset of +08:45 for example.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I thought. The question was more academic in the realm of 'why would you throw away a piece of (questionably valuable) info if it cost you merely a byte in storage and bandwidth'. And I ran into a scenario were I was validating a file name (with encoded datetime) against the modified date. So when reading the files in non-GMT time zones, the comparison fell on its face. I can certainly get around it, but 'just wondering'.

Comment: Ah, it seemed more like a question asking whether it is expected to do this or not, to which we don't have a precise answer. Regarding the "why would servers use UTC", it really depends. *[Should servers have their timezone set to GMT/UTC?](http://serverfault.com/questions/191331/should-servers-have-their-timezone-set-to-gmt-utc)* from Server Fault might shed some light on the various possible pros/cons.

Answer (score 1):

It's fairly standard practice to use UTC on servers and it looks like Google Drive is no exception. If they are storing dates as UTC then there would be no reason to store your device specific time zone.

If you know that the server will always give you UTC dates then you can convert them back to the local timezone of the device.

Comment: Thanks, needless to say both the answers are correct, I just couldn't pick both.